# How does this javascript import of kurento-utils get recognized?

Tags: javascript, webrtc, bower, kurento

On this line: 
https://github.com/Kurento/kurento-tutorial-java/blob/master/kurento-player/src/main/resources/static/index.html#L24

This javascript file is imported. However, there is no file called "kurento-utils.js" in this package. So how does this work? Is this some magic of bower?

Where does that file come from and how can I get it to be accessible in my code?

When I run this code, I get:

(index):281 Uncaught ReferenceError: kurentoUtils is not defined

Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Where is no magic:

```
 git clone https://github.com/Kurento/kurento-utils-js 
 cd kurento-utils-js-master
 npm install
```

To build the browser version of the library you'll only need to exec the grunt task runner and they will be generated on the dist folder. Alternatively, if you don't have it globally installed, you can run a local copy by executing:

> node_modules/.bin/grunt

(for windows i run grunt.cmd)

```
 cd kurento-utils-js-master/dist
```

Here we are

- copy kurento-utils.js in your resource folder

Comment: Where to put kurento-utils.js folder? in node_modules?